# How to add a dynamic frame to the String?

Tags: swift, uikit

I need to make a frame around the text. The length of the text is always dynamic from 8 to 12 characters (if it is important).
Added a screenshot. Above is how it looks now, and below is how it should be

```
func setupUI() {
        internationalNumberPlate.setTextStyle(.callout)
        internationalNumberPlate.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        internationalNumberPlate.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        internationalNumberPlate.numberOfLines = 1
        internationalNumberPlate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let labelSize = internationalNumberPlate.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 20))
        internationalNumberPlate.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: labelSize)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put the label inside a view with padding from the label to the view. Don't give the view a width or height. Add the border to the view only.